# Reorder array backwards with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

I am trying to reorder a C string backwards using pointers.   In my program I take in the string and then in the `for` loops I rearrange it.

For example, if I input `Thomas`, then it should return `samohT` using pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int lengthString;

    char name[256];
    cout << "Please enter text: ";
    cin.getline(name, 256);
    cout << "Your text unscrambled: " << name << endl;

    lengthString = strlen(name);

    cout << "length " << lengthString << endl;

    char* head = name;

    char* tail = name;

    for (int i = 0; i < lengthString; i++)
    {
       //swap here?

    }

    for (int j = lengthString - 1; j > -1; j--)
    {
        //swap here?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing in those two loops?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < halfOfSize; i++) { swap(string[i],string[size-1-i]);} ?

Comment: I am required to use pointers here

Comment: How come you are required to modify in-place a char* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < (lengthString / 2); ++i)
{
    char tempChar = name[i];
    name[i] = name[lengthString - i - 1];
    name[lengthString - i - 1] = tempChar;
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
char* head = name;
char* tail = name + lengthString - 1;
while (head<tail)
{
    char tempChar = *head;
    *head = *tail;
    *tail = tempChar;
    ++head;
    --tail;
}
```

Comment: @mystycs There was a line missing. Try it again, it works now (tested it).

Comment: Trying to cram assignments and increments onto a single line of code just makes for confusion and impedes clarity. Use the two extra lines that make it trivial to understand. Don't even make yourself have to think about sequence points.

Comment: @David Heffernan Okay, divided that 2 lines into 4.

Comment: That's much better, I approve now, +1

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be writing a mix of C and C++ but your assignment requires C strings. I would write it like this.

```
char str[] = "Thomas";
size_t head = 0;
size_t tail = strlen(str)-1;
while (head<tail)
{
    char tmp = str[head];
    str[head] = str[tail];
    str[tail] = tmp;
    head++;
    tail--;
}
```

You can write this algorithm with fewer variables but I personally find this version easier to read, understand and validate.

If you prefer to use pointers rather than indices then it looks like this:

```
char str[] = "Thomas";
char *head = str;
char *tail = str + strlen(str) - 1;
while (head<tail)
{
    char tmp = *head;
    *head = *tail;
    *tail = tmp;
    head++;
    tail--;
}
```

The two versions are practically indistinguishable.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, You could just use [**std::reverse**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

For example:

```
std::string str = "Thomas";
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the for-loops in your program, you can do it like this for example:

```
char reverse[256] = {0};
int reverseIndex = 0;

for (int i = lengthString - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  reverse[reverseIndex++] = name[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please enter text: ";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::cout << "Your text unscrambled: " << s << '\n';
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << "Your text scrambled: " << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realize this is not what you want since you're dealing with char*.